# Data binding not working in Template10 template VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, migration, template10

I try to create a VB.NET version of the [Template10 UWP](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) hamburger template.

The template is almost ready, but after execution I have a problem with the data binding of the ViewModels.

The MainPage page contains a TextBox and a "Submit" button. After press this button the TextBox data need to send to the DetailsPage page with data binding, but it's not working. Always the default text showing instead of the TextBox data.

I think the problem is related to more files, therefore I can only send the complete solution of the template, not only code blocks (sorry for this): [VB.Net solution](https://1drv.ms/f/s!ArRwzOSGzCWFj4Ypf27em5ffQiC4_A)

Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

In DetailPage.xaml I need modify the following section:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

to this:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:DetailPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
```

Now it's working.

Comment: Woah! Is that the default XAML in the Detail.xaml page?

Comment: No, this is my first wrong conversion in the VB.Net version, but after this fix its working.